# Module is not connected during precompilation. C++20

Tags: c++, c++20

I have 3 files (foo.cppm, foo2.cppm and bar.cpp):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRApu.png)

foo2.cppm:

```
export module K;

export int sq(int x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

foo.cppm:

```
export module M;
import K;

export int f(int x) {
    return 2 + sq(x);
}
export double g(double y, int z) {
    return y * z;
}
```

bar.cpp:

```
import M;
import K;

int main() {
    sq(f(5));
    g(0.0, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

First, I precompile the foo2.cppm:

> clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 --precompile foo2.cppm -o K.pcm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU5Cw.png)

Then I try to precompile foo.cppm:

> clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 --precompile foo.cppm -o M.pcm

and I get the error:

> foo.cppm:2:8: fatal error: module 'K' not found

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0KkV.png)

Clang version: 12.0.5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFNhb.png)

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Modules and Precompilation are not designed to work (well) together.

Choose one - and to save you from further trouble please choose precompilation until the implementation has matured more.

Comment: This is an educational example, I am trying to repeat what is described on the ninth slide of this article: https://habr.com/en/company/yandex_praktikum/blog/554874/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try following steps to compile it

```
clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 --precompile foo2.cppm -o K.pcm
clang++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 --precompile foo.cppm -o M.pcm -fmodule-file=K="K.pcm"
clang++ bar.cpp --std=c++20 -c -fprebuilt-module-path=.
clang++ bar.o K.pcm M.pcm -o exe
./exe
```

Comment: When I try to do the 3rd step I get: clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fprebuilt-module-path=.' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]

Comment: @ilich it happens because option ```-c``` means *only compile, do not link*, so any linker-related command line arguments are ignored, therefore you get that warning. In real life your compiler call provide some linker input(you can check in using ```-v``` option), so the only way to remove this warning is to remove ```-c```(but this would lead to compiler error)

Comment: got it, thanks, but maybe something can be done to run this example.

Comment: @ilich You mean without warning? I don't know such, but with this code you can launch your sample

Comment: no, does not work. I have: fatal error: module 'M' not found

Comment: @ilich Is your command exactly the same as I typed in my answer?

Comment: yes, 3rd step don't work: clang++ bar.cpp --std=c++20 -v -fprebuilt-module-path=.

Comment: @ilich what is the output of ```clang++ --version```? In my case clang++-12 works perfectly but clang++-11 and clang++-10 do not

Comment: I have clang++-12